# 80s TV action series about an "electric man"

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, action

I'm looking for an 80s tv-series. The main character was some kind of superhero-ish. He had a blue sparkling/glowing body, and he "healed" himself with electricity. He had a "sidekick" who was a star (literally a star, as in twinkle twinkle), and I keep thinking that the stars name was Orco or something similar, but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like [Automan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automan) from 1983-1984 about a glowing blue superhero fueled by electricity:

> Automan (the "Automatic Man") follows the adventures of a police officer and computer programmer named Walter Nebicher (Desi Arnaz, Jr.), who had created an artificially intelligent crime fighting program that generated a hologram (Chuck Wagner) able to leave the computer world at night and fight crime. While in the real world, Automan posed as a government agent by the name of "Otto J. Mann."
>
> Cursor was his sidekick, a floating, shifting polyhedron which could "draw" and generate physical objects as needed. The most common forms taken were a car (the Auto Car), an airplane, and a helicopter, all of which could defy the laws of physics.

Here's the intro:

Comment: Of course it was created by the same guy who came up with Knight Rider. This is magical, thanks for sharing the video, Walt.

Comment: Classic TV show, I remember the improbably 90 degree turns the car could make